# Visual Studio: Dependency woes: Cannot open include file: 'visa.h': No such file or directory

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dependencies

**Situation:** 
Migrating an old codebase with 1 solution and 60 projects from an old machine (Win10 Visual Studio 2019 Community 64bit) to a new machine (Win10 Visual studio community 2022 64bit) and it won't compile on new machine.

Compiling in Debug Win32

The error I'm getting tens of times for various projects

```
Error   C1083   Cannot open include file: 'visa.h': No such file or directory
```

But if I right click the:

```
#include <visa.h>
```

"Go to document" works just fine...

**On the old machine:** 
Under Configuration Properties -> VC++ Directories -> Include Directories -> ($(VC_IncludePath);$(WindowsSDK_IncludePath)) 
Under Configuration Properties -> VC++ Directories -> Library Directories -> ($(VC_LibraryPath_x86);$(WindowsSDK_LibraryPath_x86))

Under Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Additional Include Directories ->

> $(ProgramFiles)\IVI Foundation\VISA\WinNT\include 
> $(ProgramFiles)\National Instruments\NI-DAQ\DAQmx ANSI C Dev\include

Which correctly evaluates to:

> C:\Program Files **(x86)**\IVI Foundation\VISA\WinNT\include 
> C:\Program Files **(x86)**\National Instruments\NI-DAQ\DAQmx ANSI C Dev\include

**On the new machine:** 
It incorrectly evaluates to:

> C:\Program Files\IVI Foundation\VISA\WinNT\include 
> C:\Program Files\National Instruments\NI-DAQ\DAQmx ANSI C Dev\include

Forcing the correct evaluation with

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\IVI Foundation\VISA\WinNT\include" 
> "C:\Program
> Files (x86)\National Instruments\NI-DAQ\DAQmx ANSI C Dev\include"

Still throws the same errors...
I am also concerned that only the header files are included. Don't the library files need to be included somehow too? Though on the old machine they don't seem to be.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Vs 2019 wasn't 64bit, 2022 is the first 64bit version, presumably the `ProgramFiles` variable is being evaluated in a 64-bit context now instead of 32-bit which is why it has the 64 bit value rather than the 32-bit one. When you changed the configuration to hard code the path are you sure you changed the configuration that you're currently building?

Comment: @AlanBirtles - If I understand what you mean, in the Build Configuration Manager, everything is set as Win32 or "Any CPU". 

Do you think a janky work-around would be to download vs 2019 community and give that a shot? I've been banging my head against this issue for a while and I think I'm about ready to give that a shot.